# Label issue in doughnut chart using chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

```html
 $(document).ready(function(){
 function call() {
   $.ajax({
 url: "chartjs/tempdata.php",
 method:"GET",
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  var difference=[];
  var percentage=[];
  var finaldata=[];
  
  for(var i in data) {
   //time.push( data[i].timeid+"hr");
   percentage.push(data[i].soc);
   percentage[0]=(percentage[0]/1000);
percentage[0]=Number(Math.round(percentage[0]+'e2')+'e-2');
      }
 difference[0]=100-percentage[0];
 finaldata[0]=difference[0];
 finaldata[1]=percentage[0];
  var data = {
    labels: [
        "uncharged",
        
        "charged"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: finaldata,
            backgroundColor: [
                "#282828",
               
                "#FFFFFF"
            ],
            /*hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#282828",
               
                "#FFFFFF "
             ]*/
        }]
};

var options = {        
     cutoutPercentage: 80
};


//var option = {scales: { yAxis:}}
        //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#fff';

    var ctx = $("#candnut");
    var lineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'doughnut',
     data: data,
     options: options

    });
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
        type = chart.config.type;

    if (type == 'doughnut')
    {
     var percent = Math.round((chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] * 100) /
                    (chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] +
                    chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[1]));
   var oldFill = ctx.fillStyle;
      var fontSize = ((height - chart.chartArea.top) / 100).toFixed(2);
      
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle"

      var text = percentage[0] + "%",
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = (height + chart.chartArea.top) / 2;
   
      ctx.fillStyle = chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[1];
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.fillStyle = oldFill;
      ctx.save();

    }
  }
});

 },
 error: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 }

   });
}
call();
setInterval(call, 10000);
});
```

I am trying to display label at the center of the doughnut hart using chartjs and displaying well but when value of the percentage changes it gets overlapped. I searched for it on net and there is similar Label inside doughnut chart issue#78 on github.

I am unable to figure out why it is happening.

now i added my code.
And in your case when user hover over it then only it is visible.
but in my chart i just have two fields and i want to show one of them at center.

Comment: thanks for adding your code.  I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are drawing on top of the previous state because you are using `ctx.restore()` and `ctx.save()` wrapped around your canvas drawing logic.  Try removing this and it should work.  Also, you might want to put your logic in the `afterDraw` callback (instead of `beforeDraw`).

Also, here is another approach to implementing the same behavior but it uses custom tooltips instead.  This is nice because it gives you way more flexibility to change the look and feel via html/css.  Your approach is limited to understanding the canvas API to paint pixels.

Basically, you use an external custom tooltip positioned in the middle of the chart that is triggered when a chart segment is hovered.

Here is the relevant code

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.custom = function(tooltip) {
  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var total = 0;

    // get the value of the datapoint
    var value = this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data[tooltip.dataPoints[0].index].toLocaleString();

    // calculate value of all datapoints
  this._data.datasets[tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex].data.forEach(function(e) {
      total += e;
    });

    // calculate percentage and set tooltip value
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<h1>' + (value / total * 100) + '%</h1>';
  }

  // calculate position of tooltip
  var centerX = (this._chartInstance.chartArea.left + this._chartInstance.chartArea.right) / 2;
  var centerY = ((this._chartInstance.chartArea.top + this._chartInstance.chartArea.bottom) / 2);

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = centerX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = centerY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._fontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.fontSize;
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._fontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};
```

And a [working example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/vxNRmW) as well.